# working with .env file (dotenv)

Tags: configuration

I created an env file as named '.env' for kept the project keys. But I could not see in folder this file. how do i update this file later on Mac?

how do I update this file if I want to add anything else later?
thank you.

Comment: The `.` in front of `.env` means that it is a hidden file. You need to enable viewing of hidden files on your Mac.

Comment: okey i see I solved this problem by viewing the hidden files :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot files in UNIX systems are not often displayed by default:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory

Specifically, `.env` file is used by many JavaScript projects and it is supported by a [dotenv NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Such common tools in Ethereum world include Truffle, OpenZeppelin SDK and others.

Three ways to display this file

- Your editor like Visual Studio Code should display these files by default if you do `Add folder to Workspace` action
- On the command line shell, you can list all files with `ls -lha` command
- In macOS Finder you can press CMD + SHIFT + . to display them, but you can also turn [them visible all the time](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/show-hidden-files-mac-3520878/)

Comment: thank you I made cmd +shft +. and solved it :)